# Unexpected output for most numbers given in. (Python)

Tags: python, loops, primes

I'm trying to make a Prime Factorisation code in Python, here's what I did so far:

```
# Prime Factorisation
while True:
    try:
        n, primes, factorisation, dividers, factors = abs(int(input('Enter an integer to find it\'s Prime Factorisation: '))), [], [], [], [] # Asks for input and assigns multiple variables and lists
        break
    except:
        print('Please enter an integer.')
def isprime(num): # Checks if given number is prime
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
    return len(factors)== 2
for i in range(2,n+1):
    if isprime(i):
        primes.append(i)
for i in primes: # This code does the actual Prime Factorisation
    while n % i == 0: # If n (The input the user gave) is divisible by i of list primes: 
        factorisation.append(n) # n is added to factorisation
        dividers.append(i) # i is added to divisors
        n /= i  # n = n / i
output = str(dividers).replace(', ',' x ').replace('[','').replace(']','') # Pretties up the list dividers
print(str(factorisation[0]) + ' = ' + output) # Prints given value and divisors
```

The code works for numbers like 256 but gives weird outputs with other numbers, please help me find me mistake, thank you!

Comment: "gives weird outputs with other numbers" - what's weird about them?

Comment: factors should be a local variable inside the function definition of isprime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example (the trouble was with the shared "factors" list variable).

```
# Prime Factorisation
while True:
    try:
        n, primes, factorisation, dividers, factors = abs(int(input(
            'Enter an integer to find it\'s Prime Factorisation: '))), [], [], [], []  # Asks for input and assigns multiple variables and lists
        break
    except:
        print('Please enter an integer.')


def isprime(num):  # Checks if given number is prime
    factors = []

    for i in range(1, num + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)

    return len(factors) == 2


for i in range(2, n + 1):
    if isprime(i):
        primes.append(i)

for i in primes:  # This code does the actual Prime Factorisation
    while n % i == 0:  # If n (The input the user gave) is divisible by i of list primes:
        factorisation.append(n)  # n is added to factorisation
        dividers.append(i)  # i is added to divisors
        n /= i  # n = n / i

output = str(dividers).replace(', ', ' x ').replace('[', '').replace(']', '')  # Pretties up the list dividers

print(str(factorisation[0]) + ' = ' + output)  # Prints given value and divisors
```

Outputs

```
# > python test.py
Enter an integer to find it's Prime Factorisation: 247
247 = 13 x 19
```

### Cleaner version

Just a cleaner version of the source code

```
# Prime Factorisation
while True:
    try:
        n = abs(int(input(
            'Enter an integer to find it\'s Prime Factorisation: ')))  # Asks for input and assigns multiple variables and lists
        break
    except:
        print('Please enter an integer.')


def isprime(num):  # Checks if given number is prime
    return len([n for n in range(1, num + 1) if num % n == 0]) == 2


primes = [n for n in range(2, n + 1) if isprime(n)]

factorisation, dividers = [], []
for i in primes:  # This code does the actual Prime Factorisation
    while n % i == 0:  # If n (The input the user gave) is divisible by i of list primes:
        factorisation.append(n)  # n is added to factorisation
        dividers.append(i)  # i is added to divisors
        n /= i  # n = n / i

output = str(dividers).replace(', ', ' x ').replace('[', '').replace(']', '')  # Pretties up the list dividers

print(str(factorisation[0]) + ' = ' + output)  # Prints given value and divisors
```

Answer (score 0):

The local variable factors in the function isprime is missing:

```
def isprime(num): # Checks if given number is prime
    factors = []
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
    return len(factors)== 2
```

Works fine, after this correction

Answer (score 0):

This function is broken:

```
...
factors = []
...

def isprime(num): # Checks if given number is prime
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
    return len(factors)== 2
```

So, `isprime` will continue appending `i` to the *global* variable `factors` over and over again, even if it already contains this number. So, the length of `factors` will continue growing past 2. In fact, for `n == 255` `factors` will contain 1456 numbers! The function will return `False` for any number greater than 2, and the only prime number found will be 2.

You need to make `factors` local:

```
def isprime(num): # Checks if given number is prime
    factors = []
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
    return len(factors) == 2
```

Or use a generator expression in order to not waste memory:

```
def isprime(num):
    factors = (f for f in range(1, num + 1) if num % f == 0)

    assert next(factors) == 1 # this is always true

    try:
        # this will be true if there are no more factors other than `num` itself
        return next(factors) == num
    except StopIteration:
        # There are no more factors, so `num` must equal 1, which is not prime
        return False
```